# VBA Absolute Formula range changing when running a copy + Paste macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am running a copy paste macro but when I run it, it keeps changing the range of my formula to the last of row.

For example, my original VLOOKUP formula looks from `$D$2:$G$5000`, but when I run my macro it will change it to `$D$2:$G$1254` where 1254 is the last row where data resides.

Here is the copy + paste function:

```
Sub START1()

Dim shCurrentWeek As Worksheet
Dim shPriorWeek As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long

Set shCurrentWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Week")
Set shPriorWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prior Week")
lr = shCurrentWeek.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Copies Current Week into Prior Week and deletes Rows in Prior week

shCurrentWeek.Range("A4:X" & lr).Copy
shPriorWeek.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
shPriorWeek.Range("A" & lr - 2 & ":A10000").EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

any ideas?

Comment: When you delete rows, Excel will automatically adjust any formulas which reference the deleted rows (even if they're using absolute references).  Try clearing the rows instead of deleting them.

Comment: if the rows from 1254 to 5000 are getting deleted anyway, why does it matter? The lookup will still work with 1254 being the last data row, right?

Comment: Yes, but i run another macro which inserts new data, that new data might go past the 1254 rows which is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [INDIRECT()](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) function so the formula will always reference the rows you wish. Here's a simple example (please see [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) for way more detailed info):

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start you are using pastevalues so you will not be getting any formulas on your second page but your error lies with the last row of your code

```
shPriorWeek.Range("A" & lr - 2 & ":A10000").EntireRow.Delete
```

Because your formula overlaps this range that you are deleting excel automatically adjusts the vlookup formula.

I would suggest deleting your data before pasting the values.

*edit after reading the comments if the formulas are already on the page then this solution will not work and I would use clearcontents instead as per tim's suggestion.